# Whats the reason why it needs to have default value on toggle menu?

Tags: menu, toggle

Filter button [image] 
Users allow to choose the filter (toggle menus - Last 4 hours, Last 24 Hours, Yesterday, Last Week and Last Month) and the date range to change the details of a graph (not shown), if user selects or update into  a specific date range, the toggle menu filters (as my boss wants) will be off, means deselected - removing a default value. But I don't want to do that, cause it will probably confuse users if the toggle menus means on or off or even disabled. With my other concept where Specific Date Range is part of the toggle menus but it requires 2 actions (choosing Specific Date Range and update the dates), also it doesn't need to autoupdate while Specific Date Range is selected thats why I have a Filter button next to it.

Comment: Do the toggle buttons update the date range fields like a preset? Then it makes sense to remove the selected state from the buttons when none of them meets the current value.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce "Custom" option for that. This way something always will be selected. See examples for 3 different states:

[image: Date pickers or Date labels on demand]

Comment: as mentioned, I made this already, but use "SPECIFIC DATE RANGE" instead of CUSTOM and still these requires 2 actions Select CUSTOM, Pick Dates, and UPDATE . And it needs not to autoupdate, that makes it 3actions.

Comment: In general it's not always a good thing to optimize for reducing number of clicks at all stakes - easiness and clarity are more important. 
Why do you consider autoupdating a bad thing? For "Last 4 Hours" I'm expecting that clicking on the button will be enough to show me the chart from last 4 hours. For specific date range, I expect that changing either start or end date will update the chart respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Does it need to update right away after the START DATE was changed or after the END DATE was changed? what is your suggestion?

Comment: I often filter data from both ends (either start date, end date or both)...it really depends on the filtering context of your end User. If you expect or have the data to confirm that the Users always change both dates - refresh only after changing end date, if not - refresh regardless of the date changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons of this.
1. It is to guide user that which are the ways to access the information. So that they can search for data accordingly.
2. Listed data are shown based on which parameter. For example, default listing order is in recently first order if default value in drop down is selected so.

So the main aim to show default values is to guide the user and to make it meaningful to the user to use the system or to access the information.